# Jquery accordian: How to target only the child class of a clicked element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, accordion

### DEMO

---

Below is an example of a simple working accordian.

**HTML**

```
<div class="Accordian">
    <div class="Btn">BUTTON
        <div class="Icn"><i class="Up"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Content">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function ($) {
    $('.Accordian').find('.Btn').click(function () {
        var $content = $(this).siblings('.Content').slideToggle('fast');
        $('.Content').not($content).slideUp('fast');
        //How to toggle only child of clicked?
        $('.Icn i').toggleClass('Up').toggleClass('Down');            
    });
});
```

---

The problem is simple. Class **`.Up`**/**`.Down`** will be css icons that toggle on click.
Currently my code toggles all classes named up/down.

**QUESTION**

How to target only the child class of the clicked element and apply appropriate class?

How I suspect it should work:

```
onclick
If accordian closed

 - Apply class .Up to clicked element.  
 - Apply class .Down to all closed elements. 

Else

 - Vice versa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find element `.Icn i` in clicked elements context.You need to use:

```
$('.Icn i').not($(this).find('.Icn i')).removeClass('Down').addClass('Up');
$(this).find('.Icn i').toggleClass('Up').toggleClass('Down');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2aME4/)**

Comment: I love simple solutions. This almost works however, open one, then open another without closing first.

Comment: Many thinks I almost had it worked out but you beat to to it.